# ParseError using Typeahead Ajax in WordPress Multisite

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to create a custom MultiBlog Search for WordPress, where you can search for specific words, tags, authors, categories, date range, and comments.

You can search in every blog, just selected blogs, or just one. Results are fine but I'm getting some problems with TypeHead autocomplete.

For tags, categories and authors only I'm using TypeHead via Ajax.

I'm sure I'm getting all values from HTML, so here's my JS :

```
var form = $('#multiselect-search-form');
   $('#categories').typeahead({
        source: function(query, process) {
            $.ajax({
                url: BaseURL + 'wp-content/plugins/multiblogselect/categories-search.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: form.serialize(),
                dataType: 'JSON',
                async: true,
                success: function(data) {
                    categories = [];
                    map = {};
                    $.each(data, function (i, categorie) {
                        map[categorie.name] = categorie;
                        categories.push(categorie.name);
                    });
                    process(categories);
                    console.log(categories);
                },
                error: function(req, err){ console.log('Ajax error ' + err); }
            });
        }
    });
```

Actually it works fine when i look just in one blog (whatever, just one selected). But when I'm trying to select more than 1 blog, I'm getting parsererror.

So here's my PHP :

Getting values is fine, I'm sending them to JS. $multiblogselect returns me ID of blog in array.

```
if (is_array($multiblogsselect)){
        $multiselect = count($multiblogsselect);
        if ($multiselect === 1) {
            foreach ($multiblogsselect as $key => $value){
                if ($value != 1 && $value > 0) {
                    $tablePrefix = $wpdb->base_prefix.$value.'_';
                } else{
                    $tablePrefix = $wpdb->base_prefix;
                }

                $resultCategories = getPostCategories($tablePrefix, $categories);
                echo json_encode(array_values($resultCategories));
            }
        } else {
            $resultCategories = array();
            for ($i=1; $i<=$multiselect; $i++) {
                if ($i != 1 && $i > 0) {
                    $tablePrefix = $wpdb->base_prefix.$i.'_';
                } else{
                    $tablePrefix = $wpdb->base_prefix;
                }
                $resultCategories = array_merge_recursive($resultCategories, getPostCategories($tablePrefix, $categories));
            }
            echo json_encode(array_values($resultCategories));
        }
}
```

So i can search in database using whatever prefix is used, in a loop

```
    function getPostCategories($tablePrefix, $categories){
    //object_id in term_relationships is post_id
    global $wpdb;
    $queryCategories = "SELECT name
                    FROM ".$tablePrefix."term_relationships
                    JOIN ".$tablePrefix."term_taxonomy
                    ON ".$tablePrefix."term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = ".$tablePrefix."term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
                    JOIN ".$tablePrefix."terms
                    ON ".$tablePrefix."terms.term_id = ".$tablePrefix."term_taxonomy.term_id
                    WHERE ".$tablePrefix."terms.name LIKE '%".$categories."%'
                    AND ".$tablePrefix."term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
                    ";
    $resultCategories = $wpdb->get_results( $queryCategories );
    return $resultCategories;
}
```

So, it works fine when i'm searching in just one blog, but not if I select multiple blogs (getting ParseError).

Any idea ?

EDIT : i've added "for" loop, so i don't not have parseerror anymore. However, returned array is empty on multiple blog search. array_merge in cause ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax :

```
if (is_array($multiblogsselect)){

    $multiselect = count($multiblogsselect);

    if ($multiselect === 1) {
        foreach ($multiblogsselect as $key => $value){
            if ($value != 1 && $value > 0) {
                $tablePrefix = $wpdb->base_prefix.$value.'_';
            } else {
                $tablePrefix = $wpdb->base_prefix;
            }

            $resultCategories = getPostCategories($tablePrefix, $categories);
            echo json_encode(array_values($resultCategories));
        }
    } else {
        $resultcategories = array();
        foreach ($multiblogsselect as $key => $value) {
          if ($value == 1) {
            $resultCategories[$key] = getPostCategories($tablePrefix = $wpdb->base_prefix, $categories);
          } else {
            $resultCategories[$key] = getPostCategories($tablePrefix = $wpdb->base_prefix.$value.'_', $categories);
          }
        }
    echo json_encode(array_values($resultCategories));
    }
}
```